# How can a write correct rewrite rules in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I havve been using an htaccess file to create rewrites so as not to not have to include .php/.html filenames in my urls.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-page.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example-page.com
    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   /front    /front_page.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   /redirect    /redirect-page.php
```

However as my code is currently written the redirects are not working and all attempts at loading the pages with anything else besides the filenames is giving me a 404 error. How might i fix my code to get the redirecting to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the directives like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^front$ /front_page.php [L]

RewriteRule ^redirect$ /redirect-page.php [L]
```

There doesn't seem to be a need for all your additional *conditions*? I assume you only have the one domain `example-page.com` and you don't have a file called `/front` etc.

In `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. You should also include start/end-of-string anchors on the regex so that you only match `front` exactly and not match it *anywhere* in the URL-path.